# Why does Serialized field not show up in inspector when set to static?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im pretty new to unity and c# in general.

Trying to create an array based on a int value im trying to serialize.
No Errors but when i set the Serialize field to static it doesnt show up in the inspector.
Anyone know why or a work around?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using UnityEngine;

public class Variables : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    [SerializeField] static int size = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int Arraysub = 0;
    bool runArray = false;
    int[] array = makeArray(size);
    void Start()
    {
     

    }
    static int[] makeArray(int size){
        int[] MethodArray = new int[size];
        return MethodArray;

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(size > 0){
            runArray = true;
        }
        while(index < array.Length && runArray){
        Arraysub++;
        array[index] = Arraysub;
        print(array[index]);
        index++;
        
        }
    }
}
```

To Create an array using serialzedfield.

Comment: because its not per instance

Comment: This is the second rule: [SerializationRules](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html#SerializationRules)

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned this is clearly stated in the [Serialization Rules](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html#SerializationRules)

> To use field serialization you must ensure that the field:
>
> - Is public, or has a SerializeField attribute
> - **isn’t static**
> - ...

Also if you think about it: How/Where should it be serialized?

If something is `static` it doesn't belong to a single instance of your type. It rather belongs to the type itself!

So in which of your asset instances of that type should the field be serialized then? -> of course: in none!

---

My question would be why you need this to be `static` in the first place at all?

The most straight forward solution will probably be: Make this a non-static instance field and be done with it.

Then rather solve the underlying issue which lead you to the requirement for that to be `static` in the first place.

My guess would be that

```
int[] array = makeArray(size);
```

Instead you can simply do

```
[SerializeField] private int size;

int[] array;

private void Awake()
{
    array = new int[size];
}
```

Or alternatively even

```
[SerializeField] private int[] array;
```

in which case the array itself is directly serialized into the Inspector where you can add, remove, modify and rearrange the contained elements.

---

**IF** you really need to serialize a value and want it to be shared among multiple instances the most straight forward way would be using a [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html)

This is basically a "data container" asset (=> referencable from everywhere) and can hold your values (and of course also behavior - it's a c# class after all)

This could look like

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class SharedVariables : ScriptableObject
{
    public int size;
}
```

You create an instance of this in the Assets (Project View) via <kbd>right click</kbd> → `Create` → `SharedVariables`

Call it whatever you like and adjust your value(s)

And then you can reference this wherever needed

```
[SerializeField] private SharedVariables sharedVariables;

...

int[] MethodArray = new int[sharedVariables.size];
```